How can I rewrite a for loop with multiple (nested) if statements to get faster runtimes?
My code currently looks like:
for j in range(len(destined)):
        if destined[j] == 1:
            if den[j,i+1] == 0:
                is_dense = np.hstack((is_dense, j))
            elif den[j,i+1] < den_min:
                is_diffuse = np.hstack((is_diffuse, j))

Looking for help on how to speed this up. This is too slow, since destined and den[:,i+1] are both 1-d arrays with lengths of ~68 million. The conditions and what happens under them isn't important. Any tips for how to do the "for -> if -> if elif" nested structure more efficiently?
Edit: I see how np.hstack is stupid when I'm essentially just using it to append. That's from prior coding attempt where I was actually trying to hstack arrays. My question is more looking for a better way to accomplish what the "for -> if -> if or elif" logic train is accomplishing

Why not for j in destined: instead of using range?

What is i in your code? Looks like you missed a loop.

don't do things like this: np.hstack((is_dense, j)) in a loop

The conditions are the same except for the object being worked on. In the C world, you would speed things up by using the conditional results (boolean = int 0 or 1) as indexes to pick up a pointer to either is_dense, or is_diffuse. This saves a branch (which is slow). In Python, I don't think branches have the same relative overhead, and a list lookup is far more expensive than in C, but you could try it if you want - it's the benchmark that gives the answer.

You could also try micro-optimisations. i+1 is computed twice. For that matter den[j, i+1] is looked up twice, save it in a variable and use that.

Can you please [edit] your question and put there small input arrays and expected output?
